# How to deallocate this array

Tags: c++, memory-management

This is my simple program that has two functions, one is to create a series of Fibonacci then add it to an array. Another one is used to deallocate the array, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
int **createFibArray(int n){

    int **arr = new int*[n];
    int fnum1 = 1,fnum2=1,fnum;

    //  n== 1
    if(n == 1){
        arr[0] = new int;
        *arr[0] = 1;
        return arr;
    }

    //  n>= 2
    arr[0] = new int;
    arr[1] = new int;
    *arr[0] = 1;
    *arr[1] = 1;

    // fib calculator
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++){
        fnum = fnum1 + fnum2;
        fnum1 = fnum2;
        fnum2 = fnum;

        arr[i] = new int;
        *arr[i] = fnum;
    }
    return arr;
}


//This function takes an array pointer, and deallocates memory
void removeArray(int head[]){
    delete [] head;
    head = nullptr;
}

int main(){

    int **head = createFibArray(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout << *head[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "------" << endl;
    removeArray(*head);
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout << *head[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Why an array of pointers to a single `int`? You'll have a lot less trouble with an array of `int` and it'll most likely be the same size or smaller.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: [ASan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) told me you are allocating memory with `new` when you do `arr[0] = new int;` and `delete` it with `delete [] head;`. You are not allowed to do that. You have to match `new` with `delete` and `new []` with `delete []`.

Comment: Allocating individual `int` values is a serious drag on performance and a giant hassle for clean-ups. You're making life extremely difficult for yourself here and leaking tons of memory. Hint: `std::vector` and don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strongly consider returning an array of integers rather than an array of integer pointers. If you insist on using a raw pointer rather than an STL container:

`int **createFibArray(int n)`

Should be

`int *createFibArray(int n)`

And this:

```
int **arr = new int*[n];
```

will be this:

```
int *arr = new int[n];
```

Then you can remove the `*` from nearly every place you use it, and the delete function can remain pretty much unchanged. You will change the *call* to the delete function:

`removeArray(*head);`

becomes:

`removeArray(head);`

However, setting the value to `nullptr` in the function is worthless. either do so after the call to `removeArray` or omit it entirely if you are certain it will never be reused after being deleted.

Which brings us to the last part of your `main` function. Dereferencing a pointer after you have deleted it (or attempted to delete it in this case) is undefined behavior.